# Python 3 need help in a school project

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm taking a programming course in high school, right now and I am making a program of a game that the teacher assigned for all of us make. The game is called "game of sticks" (if you would like a better run down on how the game works skip about half way through this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dUXW3Kh_kxo&t=280s). Basically we have 15 sticks on a table and you can take away 1, 2, or 3 sticks. I have a code that works for the game but it says I'm doing an illegal move for 5 sticks left with any play. I cant find the problem and was hoping someone else could.

```
pl1 = input("Player 1, what is your username?") #player 1
pl2 = input("Player 2, what is your username?") #player 2
turnsa = 0 #player1 turns
turnsb = 0 #player2 turns
x = 15 #number of sticks
whichplayer = 1 
while(x != 1): 
 while(whichplayer == 1):
   P1 = int(input(pl1 + ', choose an amount of sticks from 1-3 ' + str(x) + 
' sticks remaining')) 
   if P1 < x and P1 < 4: # check for legal move
     x = x - P1
     turnsa = turnsa + 1
     whichplayer = 2 #ending loop to start player 2 turn
   if P1 > 3 or P1 > x: #check for illegal move
     print('illegal move')
     continue #restarting player 1 loop
 while(whichplayer == 2):
   P2 = int(input(pl2 + ', choose an amount of sticks from 1-3 ' + str(x) + 
' sticks remaining'))
   if P2 < x and P2 < 4:
     x = x - P2
     turnsb = turnsb + 1
     whichplayer = 1
   if P2 > 3 or P2 > x:
     print('illegal move')
     continue 
if turnsa > turnsb:
  print('congrats ' + pl1 + ' you win')
if turnsb > turnsa:
  print('congrats ' + pl2 + ' you win')
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample of input values that would provide the issue you are talking about?

Comment: There is more than one "illegal move rule". It will help if you print "illegal move 1" and "illegal move 2". See the behavior and check which rules are troublesome.

Comment: could you elaborate i'm not sure what you mean

Comment: and @M.G the game starts with 15 sticks and if you open this link https://repl.it/repls/PlasticAmbitiousComputeranimation and run the program it will always say illegal move when there is 5 sticks left and the guess is 3 it prints "illegal move" and when the amount of sticks is less than 5 it just repeats the question with nothing actually happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are decreasing `x` in the first `if` statement, then when the second `if` checks `P1 > x`, it's true because you set `x` from `5` to `2`, and the `P1` is `3`. You could just use an `if/else` here since if the move is not valid, you already know it will be an invalid move. Also you have some edge cases that need checking with your `>`, `<`, and `!=` comparisons (try taking 3 sticks each turn and see what happens). I will leave the rest for you to work out as this is school work and will be a good learning experience. Will edit later if assistance is needed.

```
if P1 < x and P1 < 4: # check for legal move
    x = x - P1 # <========= decrementing here then checking it in the next if
    turnsa = turnsa + 1
    whichplayer = 2 #ending loop to start player 2 turn
if P1 > 3 or P1 > x: #check for illegal move
    print('illegal move')
    continue #restarting player 1 loop
```